# need a help subtract DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net

I need to subtract `DateTimePicker1 - DateTimePicker2`

```
DateTimePicker1 get infornet from The man who ran the software
DateTimePicker2 get infornet from The man who ran the software
```

The Datetimekiper is like (`HH:mm  d/M/y`)

the date is because its can take 4 days.

so  the hour can be 72- 96

I just need the numbers of hours and minutes.

Comment: So, [what did you try](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, as DateTimePicker1.Subtract(DateTimePicker2).Hours ?

Comment: Like odded said, you need to show what did you try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be handling the `DateTime` value, not the control itself.

try something like this:

`Dim x = DateTimePicker1.value - DateTimePicker2.value`

and then this `x` will have the timespan, so you can get total hours like this:

`Dim hours = x.TotalHours`